# Ransack and nested routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have the following type of resource routing:

```
resources :cities do
  resources :restaurants
end
```

Which gives rise to the following type of routing:

```
/restaurants/:city_id/
```

In my restaurant index controller I have the usual ransack code, however when I click the search button I am redirected to /restaurants instead of /restaurants/:city_id.

How can I tweak ransack so when the search form is submitted it redirects to the url `/restaurants/:city_id` instead of `/restaurants`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can set manuel url

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: city_restaurants_path(params[:city_id]) do |f| %>
```